# how to import a matlab function in labview using mathscript node?

Tags: c#, .net

I’m struggling to understand how to call a Matlab function from Labview. I’m using Labview 2023
i have created a matlab function an saved it as an M file then i have called it in mathscript node in labview when i run it, i have that error occurred while executing script. Error message from server: ??? Error: Function definition not supported in this context"
Can anyone point me to where can i define the path of the M file of that function to be defined ?

Can anyone point me to where can i define the path of the M file of that function to be defined ?